# Motivation for Baby Rudin Theorems 2.38-2.40 (Compactness, k-cells)

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, motivation

I would appreciate some context around Baby Rudin's Theorems 2.38-2.40. It's in the section dealing with compactness. I find hard to give any motivations to these theorems in particular. Why are they important? Why are these theorems selected and not others?

These are said theorems:

\begin{array}{l}\text { 2.38 Theorem. If }\left\{I_{n}\right\} \text { is a sequence of intervals in } R^{1} \text { , such that } I_{n} \supset I_{n+1} \\ (n=1,2,3, \ldots), \text { then } \bigcap_{1}^{\infty} I_{n} \text { is not empty. }\end{array}

and

\begin{array}{l}\text { 2.39 Theorem. Let } k \text { be a positive integer. If }\left\{I_{n}\right\} \text { is a sequence of } k \text { -cells such } \\ \text { that } I_{n}\supset I_{n+1}(n=1,2,3, \ldots), \text { then } \bigcap_{1}^{\infty} I_{n} \text { is not empty. }\end{array}

and

\begin{equation}
\text { 2.40 Theorem. Every k-cell is compact. }
\end{equation}

In particular, no other book that I know uses the concept of *k-cell* so it is hard to imagine why are proofs involving it important.

Thank you!

Comment: In your theorems the $I_n=I_{n+1}$ is really $I_n\supset I_{n+1}$ in the book. It is what makes them interesting. Even though each new interval or $k$-cell can spit out some points that were in the previous one, the intersection never manages to spit out all the points.

Comment: apologies, that was a typo. I am editing it now.

Comment: I see, but in light of your knowledge of real analysis, why are these results worth proving?

Comment: 2.38 and 2.39 tell you that you can find solutions to a problem if you bracket it inside $k$-cells that enclose it and shrink. 2.40 proves compactness, which is a property that allows you to deduce global properties from only knowing that the properties are satisfied locally and are preserved by finite unions of open sets. It is also a property that allows to prove existence of limits.

Comment: I think part of the issue may just be Rudin's choice of terminology "$k$-cell" for what many other authors would just call a "box" or "cube" or "hypercube".  Otherwise Rudin's approach seems quite typical to me.

Comment: Thank you @flan, your comment hits the mark.

Comment: Thank you @NateEldredge, your remark will facilitate mapping Rudin's treatment of some topics with other books.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to prove that a set in $\mathbb R^n$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded. Theorems 2.38-2.40 are a build-up of tools for proving this fact. In general, a topological space is compact if and only if every collection of closed sets having the [finite intersection property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_intersection_property) has a non-empty intersection. Apparently, 2.39 is is a tool specially tailored for $k$-cells along this line of attack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: When studying Rudin page-by-page without assuming any other theory, you do not learn that intervals in $\Bbb R$ are compact until studying the proof of

\begin{array}{l}\text { 2.40 Theorem. Every } k \text{-cell is compact.}\end{array}

Moreover, writing in a terse style, Rudin doesn't even remark that

> $\quad$ ... every interval subset of $\Bbb R$ is compact

---

To gain an appreciation (or not) of Rudin's development the OP is encouraged to use other resources to formulate proofs of these two results:

[image]

It might have been instructive if Rudin had used the word *proposition* instead of *theorem* for some results concerning $k\text{-cells}$, so that upon reaching, say,

\begin{array}{l}\text { 2.39 Proposition. Let } k \text { be a positive integer. If }\left\{I_{n}\right\} \text { is a sequence of } k \text { -cells such } \\ \text { that } I_{n}\supset I_{n+1}(n=1,2,3, \ldots), \text { then } \bigcap_{1}^{\infty} I_{n} \text { is not empty. }\end{array}

we would be 'on notice' that this result is ancillary to the theorems.

Upon skimming his book it appears that he never uses the word *lemma* to highlight results.